# 12.04 system keeps on hanging on "setting up gconf2

Tags: 12.04

Since the update today dpkg and apt are both broken, and when I try to use them it recommends running:

```
sudo dpkg -configure -a
```

which then starts

```
configuring gconf2 (3.2.5-0Ubuntu2)
```

and just keeps on displaying this message without ever finishing it or giving any feedback at all. The same thing happens when I try to run the Update manager.

Answer (score 5):

So I ran into a similar issue and it was hanging on `/var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst` , which when I deleted I was able to configure the package.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify @Holden's answer, if `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gets stuck on a package (e.g. `gconf2`) then you can delete the package with `sudo apt-get purge gconf2`. After doing so, reattempt `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

After the updates have completed, you can choose to reinstall the package with `sudo apt-get install gconf2`.