# 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' stuck at 'Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...'

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I am new to linux/Ubuntu. I got `dpkg` error message when I run '`sudo apt-get update`':

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
.
.

Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So, I ran '`sudo dpkg --configure -a`', but it get stuck at "`Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ..`."

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python-aptdaemon (1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Setting up unity-scope-home (6.8.2+14.04.20131029.1-0ubuntu1) ...
.
.
Setting up python-imaging (2.3.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
```

Could someone please advise what should be done to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: try to do sudo apt-get purge gconf2 && sudo apt-get install gconf2

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Extra info, when it is stuck like that even a `ps a` and `htop` doesn't work. `ps a` never returns and htop simply clears out the terminal window black.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/401950/132233) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify @cnvzmxcvmcx's and @David's comments:

When `sudo apt-get update` appears to get stuck for a long time, you abort it and try again. The second time, it says that you need to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which shows it is stuck on a package.

For the OP, that package was `gconf2`. For me it was something else (`accountsservice`).

What you do, is you can delete the package, e.g. `sudo apt-get purge gconf2`.

Once that package has been deleted, you can reattempt the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and/or `sudo apt-get update`.